# How to combine two regular expression (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I am checking a string against two regular expression like so:

```
m = Pattern.compile("((http(s?)://)?)youtu.be/(\\w+)").matcher(word);
if (m.find()) {
    youtubeCodes.add(m.group(4));
}
m = Pattern.compile("((((http(s?)://)?)www.)?)youtube.com/watch\\Q?\\Ev=(\\w+)").matcher(word);
if (m.find()) {
    youtubeCodes.add(m.group(6));
}
```

Everything works how i want it to, but because the expressions are so similar, would there be a way to combine them in to one expression using the | character. I'm quite new to regular expressions and i just can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes they can be combined. Try to figure out the common parts and reuse them and put the differing parts into a group and use `|` in between. Note that you might want to use non-capturing groups (i.e. `(?: ... )` for all but `(\\w+)` - it will make the expression bigger but it will also help the regex engine (it doesn't need to capture text) and will make your life easier as well (you're only after one group so let it be (capturing) group no. 1 instead of 6, 14 or 42 etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do so. I'm not sure if it's worth do so because the result will be incredibly complicated. Anyway:

1. Step 1: use non-capturing groups `(?:)` wherever possible so you can retrieve the important part with the same expression: `"(?:(?:http(?:s?)://)?)youtu.be/(\\w+)"` and `"(?:(?:(?:(?:http(?:s?)://)?)www.)?)youtube.com/watch\\Q?\\Ev=(\\w+)"` both capture the important part in `m.group(1)`
2. Combine them like this: `(?:prefixPattern1|prefixPattern2)(importantPart)`

So here is the final code:

```
    String pattern = "(?:(?:(?:http(?:s?)://)?)youtu.be/|(?:(?:(?:(?:http(?:s?)://)?)www.)?)youtube.com/watch\\Q?\\Ev=)(\\w+)";
    m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(word);
    if (m.find()) {
        youtubeCodes.add(m.group(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Put a pipe between the 2 regular expressions like this:

```
m = Pattern.compile(
"((((http(s?)://)?)www.)?)youtube.com/watch\\Q?\\Ev=(\\w+)|((http(s?)://)?)youtu.be/(\\w+)"
).matcher(word);

if (m.find()) {
    youtubeCodes.add(m.group(6) == null ? m.group(10) : m.group(6));
}
```

Comment: Would you say that this is a better method to @tamas rev 's? He uses it so that the http(s?):// part isn't repeated. or is the difference too small to bother with?

Comment: It is probably a cleaner approach as you don't have to deal with group number but should not have any impact on perfs

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them by finding what parts are common in the two regular expressions. It's a bit tricky because in the version with "youtu.be" you don't use "www.". Try to draw a graph to visually see it if you're finding it difficult. Starting with the patterns you already have, you would get this expression:

```
 Pattern.compile("((http(s?)://)?)((youtu.be/)|(www.)?youtube.com/watch\\Q?\\Ev=)(\\w+)").matcher(word);
```